# Via fence distance to the trace?

Tags: pcb-design, transmission-line, microstrip, characteristic-impedance

We have a board design with four layers that uses coplanar waveguide with ground plane:
[image: From KiCAD's transmission lines calculator]
The trace has via fences.  Originally, the design was: *W*=0.35mm, *S*=0.2mm, and *H* approximately 0.2mm (for one of Isola dielectrics, which the manufacturer reports an epsilon of 4.04). The resulting impedance is 50Ω.

The via fence is about 1mm away from the center of the trace.

We are modifying the design to make it a two-layer board.  At 1mm board thickness, we can obtain the same 50Ω with a 0.68mm trace width, and 0.13mm clearance to the ground plane on the sides.  Or, at 1.6mm, 0.75mm width and the same 0.13mm clearance.

My question is:  do I need to adjust the distance from the via fence to the trace to compensate for the increase in the distance to the ground plane underneath?  That is, *H* (as defined in the above figure) is now approx. five times the *H* in the original board;  does that affect the required distance to the via fences?

Note:  I already increased the distance to compensate for the wider trace;  that is, I tried to maintain approx. the same distance from the via fence *to the edge of the trace*.  But that was a small increase;  I wonder whether the increase in *H* implies a significant adjustment in the via fence distance to the trace.

Comment: It depends on your signals  and criteria.

Comment: H and W are the two primary contributors to the trace impedance.  The traces as you've shown couple much more strongly to the reference planes than they do to the via fence, which is edge-on to the trace.  So the distance to the via fence has a small effect on the trace impedance, compared to H and W.  Not zero, but small.

Comment: @SteveSh ‒ for the ground plane underneath, is it because it is parallel to the trace, that it has a bigger effect on the trace impedance?  I want to confirm, because the via fence is going to be closer to the trace than the ground plane underneath.  (on the other hand, the ground plane on the top, around the trace, that one is — by definition — closer to the trace's edge than the via fence is)

Comment: "_H and W are the two primary contributors to the trace impedance_" ‒ did you mean to say _H_, _W_, and _S_?  (_S_ is definitely an important contributor to the impedance)

Comment: @Cal-linux: The reference plane (doesn't have to be a GND plane) contributes the most to the impedance because it is broadside to the trace.  If the via fence is closer to the trace than H, at some point it will start to have an appreciable effect on the trace impedance.  But the trace couples rather weakly to the via fence, and also to another trace (like in a differential pair), at least for traces made with 0.5 oz copper, ~0.7 mils thick (T in your diagram).  And as for S, it depends.  If S is greater than ~2H, then it has very little effect on the impedance.

Comment: Another comment.  Via fences also provide isolation between signals.  In some applications this is the primary reason for using via fences.

Comment: @SteveSh ‒ yes, isolation is the reason for our use of via fences.  The concern was that because the ground plane running underneath now was substantially farther away than in the original design, the via fence could inadvertently (well, inadvertently to us) have a non-negligible effect on the impedance.  (BTW, feel free to write these up as an answer, and I will accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an answer from the comments...

H and W are the two primary contributors to the trace impedance. The traces as you've shown couple much more strongly to the reference planes than they do to the via fence, which is edge-on to the trace. So the distance to the via fence has a small effect on the trace impedance, compared to H and W. Not zero, but small.

The reference plane (doesn't have to be a GND plane) contributes the most to the impedance because it is broadside to the trace. If the via fence is closer to the trace than H, at some point it will start to have an appreciable effect on the trace impedance. But the trace couples rather weakly to the via fence, and also to another trace (like in a differential pair), at least for traces made with 0.5 oz copper, ~0.7 mils thick (T in your diagram). And as for S, it depends. If S is greater than ~2H, then it has very little effect on the impedance.

One more thing. Via fences also provide isolation between signals. In some applications this is the primary reason for using via fences.